# What kind of adhesive is this?

Tags: adhesives, material-identification

A number of online videos show making an air dry clay, often used with a silicone embellishment mold.  The ingredients are starch, a little oil, and a clear, one-part liquid adhesive.  Here's an [example video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OL2S2UfKTHU) that displays the adhesive used at the beginning.

[image]

Judging by the language, these videos appear to be by Russian crafters.  The adhesive often appears in a dispenser bottle with mostly (I assume) Russian writing, many with a brand name of **Titan**.  The adhesive is typically described as just "polymer adhesive" or "polymer construction adhesive", available in hardware stores there.  It does not appear to be a form of clear PVA glue, which is popularly used in a similar way, and the characteristics of the clay sound different from cold porcelain (looks like less shrinkage, no cracking, harder/tougher result).

I've been unable to identify the adhesive (maybe not sold outside Russia?); the type of formulation, or what the equivalent would be in a product sold in the US.  The only "polymer construction adhesives" I've found are sold in caulking tubes or tubs, which implies a different consistency at a minimum.  Is anyone familiar with this adhesive, and what would be a comparable type of adhesive sold in the US?

**Additional info**

I did find this link that refers to the Titan products (and confirms that they are Russian): [Glue Titan](https://en-n.decorexpro.com/montazhnyj-klej/titan/#h2_266621).  The link includes a list of adhesives with supposedly similar performance (a wide variety of types, so not useful).  It also includes a recipe to make a DIY version.  However, that is not a polymer formulation, so I suspect it's like the DIY recipes for Mod Podge that aren't the same as the actual product.

Another link, [Titan Wild glue for polystyrene XPS foam Depron](https://numavig.com/Titan-Wild-glue.html), refers to Titan Wild, and identifies the ingredients as  copolymers of vinyl acetate.  [An Introduction to Vinyl Acetate-Based Polymers](https://www.mcpolymers.com/library/vinyl-acetate-based-polymers) describes many possible varieties of vinyl acetate-based polymers, so this information is of limited use identifying an equivalent US product.  It does suggest that the DIY formula in the other link is not the ingredients of the real product.

Comment: "...sold in caulking tubes or tubs, which implies a different consistency at a minimum."   Not necessarily. The Russians might be fine putting in a squeeze bottle what the West would keep in purpose designed containers, i.e. this stuff is contractor level strong, not like Elmers.

Comment: @rebusB, from the videos, it looks like the Titan stuff has too low a viscosity to dispense well from a caulking tube.  It's possible that something sold in the US in a tub would be comparable, but tubs aren't usually used for this type of glue because anything left in the tub would have a short shelf life, and every time you open the tub it would have a big effect on the life. Beyond that, the type of container isn't much to go on to ID an equivalent adhesive.  :-)